# Puppet random password generating

Tags: mysql, puppet, password

I am going to install around 100 mysql servers and I would like to have different root password on every of them.

I am going to use puppet mysql (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql) which is amazing. Unfortunately, it supports only passing password from puppet. The great thing is that it stores password in /root/.my.cnf file, so I can connect to mysql locally without knowing the password. So that I don't see the need to have password stored in puppet anymore.

Is there any way to generate password on the server so I don't need to store it on my puppet master?

Comment: Please add any code you have already tried, how it failed, etc...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927420/how-do-i-create-a-user-with-a-random-password-and-store-it-to-a-file-using-puppe

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
$ cat passwd.pp
exec {
    'foobar':
      command => '/usr/bin/openssl rand -base64 12 > /root/.my.cnf',
      creates => '/root/.my.cnf',
      user    => 'root',
      timeout => '-1',
      require => Package['mysql'];
}
```

But, since you will have to administer a great number of instances, you might find more useful to switch to [PAM authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html), available both in MySQL Enterprise and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pam-authentication-plugin/).

Comment: pam authentication is only available for mysql enterprise.